# Unable to retrieve the file_size for file at location: (Using Storage::download)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

When I tried use the `Storage::download(...)` - I have received the error:

```
Unable to retrieve the file_size for file at location: <path to file>.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem that made this error was an incorrect path to the file. **I have used `Storage::exists()` to check if really exist my file**, before using the `Storage::download()` method.

**However, my file didn't exist by the path that I provided.**